# Ember.js route transitionTo method not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I have a nested route, and from the action I am transitioning to a different route with `query-params`, but `transitionTo` does nothing, doesn't even report an error.

The `{{link-to}}` helper works fine, though. But I need to do it with an action.

**routes.js:**

```
this.route('parent-route', function() {
    this.route('child-route1');
    this.route('child-route2', {path: '/child-route1/child-route2/:param1/:param2'});
  });
```

**child-route1:**

```
actions: {
    doTransit() {
        this.transitionTo('parent-route.child-route2', {query-params: {'param1': '1', 'param2': '2'}});
    }
}
```

I have never seen this problem before, what could I be doing wrong?

May be the extra route-name I put in the `routes.js` file in `child-route2`? But I need that path there so the URL shows that stuff. Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try using

```
this.transitionToRoute('parent-route.child-route2', '1', '2')
```